# Show loading indication when drawing large canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, konvajs, react-konva

I'm rendering a canvas with a lot of elements. Because the high amount of elements and the complex shapes of the elements the elements are not displayed instantly, but are displayed with a delay (sometimes more than 10 seconds). During this time the whole application freezes and no loading indication is shown. Is it possible to somehow show a loading indication whenever the canvas is not completely rendered yet?

Comment: I guess it should be possible if you externalize the draw calls to a webworker on an offscreen canvas and then get it back and display the rendered image on your canvas. Since its a webworker doing the work, the webpage shouldn't be blocked and you could display a loader during the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In really depends on the app itself, drawings, and general architecture of your app.

That task can be very complex in some situations. There are some options:

### 1. Use a webworker

That is probably the best approach. You need to run a webworker and make all drawings into an offscreen canvas. It will be simple if you can use 2d native API for all drawings. If you are using Konva, take a look here: https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Web_Worker.html#page-title

I don't know any ways to run a react-konva application inside a webworker

### 2. Use incremental drawing

You need to check where the slowness comes from. From rendering? From creating too many objects? If the js thread is spending too much time to just initialize the nodes, you can create them in steps. Like create 100 nodes -> draw canvas -> wait a bit -> create 100 nodes more -> etc. That way the drawing will slowly appear on the screen and the UI probably will not be frozen.

### 3. Optimizing drawings

There are many tips here: https://konvajs.org/docs/performance/All_Performance_Tips.html#page-title